# Name of the website added next to Post title in Google Search Results

Tags: wordpress, google-search

I have a website which uses WordPress. In Google Search Results, when you search for a post, the title of the link to the post is displayed as:

Name-of-the-post | Site Title - Site address

For example, the same is on the picture below:

[image]

However, I want it to be

Name-of-the-post | Site Title

Like here:

[image]

Initially, for Site title I used the address of the website and the result was:

Name-of-the-post | Site address

However, when I added a different title for the site (from WordPress admin panel), I ended up with the text of the link as in the first picture.

I also have Yoast Seo Plugin installed, but I do not find any settings there related to Google Search results.

Is this something I can change, or is it up to Google to generate these titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google replaces your title.
For it may be different reasons.
Google write about it:

> If we’ve detected that a particular result has one of the above issues
>   with its title, we may try to generate an improved title from anchors,
>   on-page text, or other sources. However, sometimes even pages with
>   well-formulated, concise, descriptive titles will end up with
>   different titles in our search results to better indicate their
>   relevance to the query. There’s a simple reason for this: the title
>   tag as specified by a webmaster is limited to being static, fixed
>   regardless of the query. Once we know the user’s query, we can often
>   find alternative text from a page that better explains why that result
>   is relevant. Using this alternative text as a title helps the user,
>   and it also can help your site. Users are scanning for their query
>   terms or other signs of relevance in the results, and a title that is
>   tailored for the query can increase the chances that they will click
>   through.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624

Try add this meta tag to page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noodp"/>
```

Comment: I added `<meta name="robots" content="noodp"/>` to the header of the website, I believe I have to wait until Google crawls the pages and the site again to notice the changes.

Comment: I also found this https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/google-supports-meta-noodp-tag/ Although the post seems a little bit old, it describes a similar case and it says it takes about  3-4 days for the change to take place.

Comment: Yes, i will be glad, if i helped you :)